# Prove that the following sequence converges and find its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that the following sequence converges and find its limit
$$\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}},\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}},\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}}},\ldots$$

I started to define: $$a_{1}=\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}$$ 
$$a_{k}=\frac{1}{3+a_{k-1}}$$

Comment: I tried to use the cauchy sequence criteria with a3 and a2

Comment: Have you heard of continuous fractions?

Comment: I will look it up on wikipedia

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. $\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{3+a_{k-1}}$ is indeed a continuous fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it up into two sub-sequences, of odd and even indexes, $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$ , with $k\in\mathbb N$, and prove that both are strictly monotonous, and bounded. As for value, we have $x=\dfrac1{3+x}\iff x^2+3x$ $-1=0\iff x_{_{1,2}}=\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt{13}}2$ , out of which the obvious choice is the positive one.

Comment: are sub-sequences defined in set of natural numbers? is it possible to use Z too?

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the typo. Yes, generally it's possible, but in our case it's **N**.